# splide slider, small issue with an object that overflows

Tags: css, reactjs, splidejs

Hi i've been trying to find a solution for a thing it's happening.
inside my slider i have an hover effect that will move the item i little up and left, and i don't get to mek it show without adding lots of paddings to prevent the item to be hidden when overflowing.

on the following screenshot with the code below, i see that with the padding i can see the items when i hover, i have added overflow-visible in tailwind css styles and tried to add it in inline styling too, but if i delete de paddings overflow: visible does not seem to apply and my object will be cropped...

[Here the result with the paddings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2L8k.jpg)

```
<Splide hasTrack={false} options={mergedOptions} style={{ overflow: 'visible' }} className=" overflow-visible bg-red-400 p-5" > <SplideTrack className="overflow-visible bg-blue-400 p-5" style={{ overflow: 'visible' }}> {items.map((item, i) => { return ( <SplideSlide className={cn('overflow-visible bg-orange-400  p-10', gapClassName)} key={i} style={{ overflow: 'visible' }} > {item} </SplideSlide> ); })} </SplideTrack> </Splide>
```

[copy of code for easy view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQajt.png)

Here the same but without the paddings
[result on navigator after deleting paddings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8jng.jpg)

```
 return ( <Splide hasTrack={false} options={mergedOptions} style={{ overflow: 'visible' }} className=" overflow-visible bg-red-400 " > <SplideTrack className="overflow-visible bg-blue-400 " style={{ overflow: 'visible' }}> {items.map((item, i) => { return ( <SplideSlide className={cn('overflow-visible bg-orange-400  ', gapClassName)} key={i} style={{ overflow: 'visible' }} > {item} </SplideSlide> ); })} </SplideTrack> </Splide> );
```

[copy of code for easy view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akPBO.png)